# MVC4 RDLC Stops all other requests

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4, rdlc

I have implemented RDLC reports in MVC4 web application (returning pdf file bytes). Whenever a user requests a report, the web application stops all other requests for all users unless this report is rendered. Some reports are really big around 100 pages so it takes a while for web server to generate and render that report. During this time, no other requests are handled by web server. Lets say the web server is busy rendering the report, and in a new tab I try to request some other data it won't show unless that RDLC completes its operation. Same happens in development machine. Please can someone suggest is this a design flaw in my web application or is this the default behavior?

Is there a way I can fix this with Multi threading or multi tasking?

This is the report rendering code just in case if you want to see. But I just want other people to share their experiences.

```
public byte[] RenderReport(PageType pageType, string ReportFormat, string ReportPath, ReportDataSource[] ReportDataModelList, out string mimeType, ReportParameter[] ReportParameters)
    {
        LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();

        string path = Path.Combine(ReportPath);
        lr.ReportPath = path;

        foreach (ReportDataSource rds in ReportDataModelList)
        {
            lr.DataSources.Add(rds);
        }

        lr.EnableExternalImages = true;
        lr.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("PrintedBy", PrintedBy));

        foreach (ReportParameter rp in ReportParameters)
            lr.SetParameters(rp);

        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;
        string pageWidthHeight;

        if (pageType == PageType.Portrait)
            pageWidthHeight =
                "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
                "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>";
        else if (pageType == PageType.Landscape)
            pageWidthHeight =
                "  <PageWidth>11in</PageWidth>" +
                "  <PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight>";
        else
            pageWidthHeight =
                "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
                "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>";

        string deviceInfo =
            "<DeviceInfo>" +
            "  <OutputFormat>" + ReportFormat + "</OutputFormat>" +
            pageWidthHeight +
            "  <MarginTop>0.3in</MarginTop>" +
            "  <MarginLeft>0.3in</MarginLeft>" +
            "  <MarginRight>0.3in</MarginRight>" +
            "  <MarginBottom>0.3in</MarginBottom>" +
            "</DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] renderedBytes;

        renderedBytes = lr.Render(
            ReportFormat,
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);

        return renderedBytes;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post relevant code and show where the problem exactly.

Comment: @learner i have posted the code but there is nothing special about code. i just want to know the default behaviour of mvc rdlc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the issue you are observing is related to the following fact about [`ASP.NET sessions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx) (which I suppose you are using):

> Access to ASP.NET session state is exclusive per session, which means
>   that if two different users make concurrent requests, access to each
>   separate session is granted concurrently. However, if two concurrent
>   requests are made for the same session (by using the same SessionID
>   value), the first request gets exclusive access to the session
>   information. The second request executes only after the first request
>   is finished. [...]

And since browser tabs ASP.NET sessions, you are basically trying to make concurrent requests from the same session.

You can simply disable session state from your application and you will see that you can make concurrent requests:

```
<sessionState mode="Off" />
```

Obviously this is only the reason for the observed behavior. In all cases you should avoid having long running operations in your ASP.NET applications. Those operations are blocking the worker threads and thus limiting the serving capacity of your application. Ideally those long running operations should be offloaded from your ASP.NET application. For example you could have a Windows Service that will have the responsibility of generating those reports and the ASP.NET application will only schedule the report generation and the service will do the actual work.

Comment: I agree that I should create a separate service that should do the report generation work. there is huge data in our database. and if the user wants a report, asp.net takes a while to render the pdf file using MVC render report and blocks all other request until this is served. just one more question, do you think async actions alone will just solve the problem? or separate server for report generation is still the best choice?

Comment: No, async actions will not solve anything. They are useful only when you have I/O bound operations such as network calls.